# Spelling check in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, spell-checking

I want to check spelling while writing in blog/contents in the web-based application. There are few javascript plugin for the same, but none of them is working on Internet Explorer (upto IE 9) then how to achieve the spell check in IE ?
Is it possible to check spelling in textbox using HTML/javascript ?
If there is a way to do this, then can you pls provide some link or sample code ?

Comment: You want to provide spellcheck for the users on your site, or just for yourself?

Comment: Make sure the plugins you're trying support the browsers you need to support. [This plugin](https://github.com/badsyntax/jquery-spellchecker) supports "IE6+ and latest Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera".

Comment: @JonathanSampson I want to provide spellcheck on the site. it should not machine dependent.

Comment: @Ravi Well in that case, you might check [the resource](https://github.com/badsyntax/jquery-spellchecker) provided by [jbabey](http://stackoverflow.com/users/386152/jbabey).

Comment: @JonathanSampson 
is it mandatory for the resource (that you mentioned) to use php or some server side components ?

Comment: @Ravi It looks like that resource does connect to a PHP backend. Are you wanting to load a full dictionary on the front end instead?

Comment: @JonathanSampson 
yes... actually, i don't want to use server side component for this. is there any javascript library available for this ?